# How to connect Jetson TX2 and Raspberry pi 3?

Tags: c#, linux, raspberry-pi3, yolo, nvidia-jetson

I'm using YOLOv3 on Jetson TX2.
What I want to do is send YOLOv3's final output(object detection data) to Raspberry pi. 
Because I would like to detect object with USB camera on Jetson TX2 and send the data to RPi and finally print out by voice on RPi.

Simply camera -- Jetson TX2 -- Raspberry pi -- speaker.

This is the first time I've used yolo and Jetson TX2. So I have a lot of difficulties.

So I don't know how to connect Jetson TX2 and Raspberry pi3.
Which terminal should be used?
And what is the code for connecting TX2 and RPi.
Is it possible send the yolo data to Raspberry Pi??

Or is there any method sending the data via networks directly??
If so, please tell me how to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Use serial communications like i2c or can bus between Jetson and raspberry pi

Answer (score 0):

you can connect both TX2 and RPi with WiFi, and can communication between them easily.